# What happens to the members of W.I.S.E. near the end of the Psyren?

Tags: psyren

Towards the end of the manga,

> After Ageha presses Miroku to go a different way to making a society of Psi users,
>  we are shown an airstrike that flies in and demolishes a huge portion of the forest.
>  WE actually see Ageha and his friends escape, but there is no mention of Miroku and his
>  companions.  In the last chapter, it is mentioned that the world "believes" they are dead.

Are we to assume that they die? Or is it that they go off into hiding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at chapter 145 (page 4) in the manga, you can see this:

[image: Chapter 145]

Yoshina asks No. 7 about Ouroboros, and she says that it has disappeared into space again in exchange for her brother's and Grana's lives.

So, if we take the words of No. 7 seriously, yes, they died.

Comment: But since Mithra was killed in the end, doesn't what happen to Ourobros not happen? Because Yoshina altered the present (redirected WISE), that means the future could have never happened

Comment: If you read the next chapters they talk about the Time-Paradox maybe this is the reason why they still had to make the sacrifice.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't see an image?

Comment: No, I can't see anything either.

Comment: Weird i can see it....

Comment: @Washu I can't see it either. In the future, try no to directly hotlink to content hosted on other sites. Upload them to Imgur (click the image icon next to the curly brackets, on the Answer toolbar) to avoid broken content in the future.